# Boolean indexing with two conditions to include NaN

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean

I want to use boolean indexing on numpy arrays and pandas series to select all rows with a value of <x in a certain column but also rows with nan values shall be included.
I tried like in this small example but I get the error
"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

```
import numpy as np

a = [0.5, 0, 1, 17, np.nan]
b = np.array(a)
c = b[b < 3 or b == np.nan]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets, replace `or` with the `|` operator and use `np.isnan` instead of `==`.

```py
c = b[(b < 3) | np.isnan(b)]
```

The `RuntimeWarning` is perhaps because this tries to compare `NaN` values to numeric. You can try to ignore it for that session:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    c = b[(b < 3) | np.isnan(b)]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  c = b[(b < 3) | (b == np.nan)]"

Comment: Is it the same from a simple python/IPython terminal (i.e. without Pycharm)? Are you perhaps in an environment?

Comment: I updated the answer about ignoring the warning.

Comment: I just tried the same script directly from the terminal and I received the same error message

Comment: replaced `==` with `np.isnan`

Comment: Thank you, I included your update "with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):" and now it works, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

One of these should do the trick:

```
c = b[np.logical_or(b < 3, b == np.nan)]
# or
c = b[np.where((b < 3) | (b == np.nan))]
# or
c = b[(b < 3) | (b == np.nan)]
```

I don't know if there are any benefits to one over the other, but if I had to guess I'd say the `np.where` one might be slightly faster? Just a guess.

Comment: Also none of these works for me "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  c = b[np.logical_or(b < 3, b == np.nan)]"

Comment: Are you running the example you posted? Or something with more data in it?

Comment: Only the example I posted

Comment: Do any of the others have issues? I'm able to run them without an issue - maybe it's an issue with different versions of NumPy

Comment: I'm using np v1.16.0 with python 3.6 and pycharm. Edit: just updated to 1.20 and the problem remains.